# How to open a newtab page using the webbrowser module in python?

Tags: python, google-chrome

I'm currently trying to open my chrome default new tab page using the webbrowser module in python. I've gotten it to work for opening up random urls, however, when I try chrome://newtab as the url, I just get a message saying that there are "no apps installed to open this type of link".

Here's the relevant bit of code (not much):

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new_tab("chrome://newtab")
```

Yes, chrome is my default browser. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Im just guessing, really, but can you call the new tab with an empty string or just empty `.open_new_tab()`

Comment: Thanks, but the empty string just opens up a file browser, and a lack of arguments gives an error.

Comment: I tried your code. My default browser is Chrome, but it opened a new tab in IE. But when I tried it with a link as the argument, for example `http://pypi.python.org`, it opened the Chrome and typed the link in the address bar, but returned `404`.

Comment: Hm. Well, whenever I put in something like htt p://www.google.c om (spaces because I can't figure out to stop StackOverflow from autolinking it), it opens a new tab in chrome and navigates to google.com fine.

Comment: Read help for comments to learn how to avoid auto-linking!

Answer (score 5):

Notice that the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/webbrowser.html) states that:

> Note that on some platforms, trying to open a filename using this function, may work and start the operating system’s associated program. However, this is neither supported nor portable.

It has been a while since I looked at this, but my recollection is that on at least some systems, the way it works under the hood is that is passes the given URI to a system specific built-in command which then opens the URI in the system default for whatever type of URI was passed in. In other words, the default application for a given file type is used. It doesn't matter if the URI points to a local file or not. Therefore, the URI `http://examplce.comn/somefile.pdf` would open the PDF file on the system default PDF viewer, which may not be the browser. As the documentation notes, this works by accident due to the underlying implementation.

However, in a different OS, such a system specific command doesn't exist, and all URIs will be opened in a web browser.

You failed to mention which OS you are working on (and I forget which OS works which way), but I suspect you are working on an OS of the first type. You *might* (again depends on which system you have) be able override the default behavior by specifying that a specific browser be used.

You could try setting the environment variable `BROWSER` as an [os.pathsep](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.pathsep)-separated list of browsers to try in order. Check the value of `os.pathsep` (`import os; print os.pathsep`) to see which character is used by your system (usually `':'` for POSIX or `';'` for Windows) and then use that character to separate items in the list. Of course, you may need to only assign one item to the list (chrome), in which case you don't need to use the separator at all. Like this (be sure to use the correct path for your system):

```
SET BROWSER="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

Or, you could try using [`webrowser.get()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.get) to choose your browser programically. However, support for Chrome hasn't been added until [Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.get). If you are using Python 3.3+, then try:

```
import webbrowser
chrome = webbrowser.get('google-chrome') # or webbrowser.get('chrome')
chrome.open_new_tab('chrome://newtab')
```

Note: the above is untested. I don't know which system you have and am therefore not able to replicate your specific setup. YMMV.

---

**Update:**

As I now know you are on a pre-Python 3.3 windows machine perhaps the following will help. You can also register a browser so that Python knows about it:

```
pth = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
webbrowser.register('chrome', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(pth))
chrome = webbrowser.get('chrome')
chrome.open_new_tab('chrome://newtab')
```

Comment: I was trying to test this, +1 for comprehensive answer.

Comment: I'm still using Python 2.7.8, unfortunately, on windows 8. Could you expand, or maybe provide an example, of an os.pathsep-separated list of browsers? I don't have any experience with that, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Dan if you had followed the link, I suspect you could figure it out. In any event, I updated my answer to include more info about it.

Comment: You can register a browser regardless of Python version. I've added instructions for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

### Seemingly Bulletproof Rock Solid Command Line From Python Option

In development, the methods above worked well for me. Then I moved my code to a production server. I found different flavors of Windows don't all play the same with python's webdriver module - I was very bummed!

I needed a bulletproof method to open auto generated html reports in a specific order.

The code below is a modification of what I did that worked very well.

```
import subprocess as SP
import time


def display_reports_in_chrome(param_1, param_2):
    front = f'start chrome.exe {param_1}\\reports\\'  # beginning of command string
    reports_list = [
        'report_1.html', 'report_2.html', 'report_3.html', 'report_4.html']

    url_list = []
    for report in reports_list:
        url_list.append(f'{front}{param_2}\\{report}')  # complete build of commands

    for url_cs in url_list:  # url_cs = url open command string
        time.sleep(0.1)  # helps to ensure the tabs order correctly
        clo = SP.run(url_cs, shell=True, capture_output=True)  # actual shell command

        # Stuff below makes sure it worked
        check = clo.returncode == 0
        error = clo.stderr.decode('utf-8')
        url_open_ok = check and not error
        err_msg = f'{error}. Let Thom know please!'

        assert url_open_ok, err_msg
```

I should point out that I was enlightened to try this by [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/833323/451244) on SuperUser

Answer (score 0):

How about automating this using the [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) extension to Selenium?

In full disclosure, I'm the author of [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/). This package is lightweight, less verbose extension of the Selenium web driver that makes browser automation even easier. Simply install the package with `pip install browserist` and you're ready to go.

Maybe something like this?

```py
from browserist import Browser

with Browser() as browser:
    browser.open.url("https://example.com")
    browser.window.open.new_tab("chrome://newtab", "tab_1")
    browser.window.open.new_tab("https://google.com", "tab_2")
    browser.window.open.new_tab("https://github.com", "tab_3")
    browser.window.open.new_tab("http://testurl.com", "tab_4")

    print("About to quit the browser. Press Y to continue.")
    while browser.prompt.proceed_yes_or_no() is False:
        print("About to quit the browser. Press Y to continue.")
        pass
```

How it looks like:

[image]

Notes:

- When running from a terminal, the browser will be kept open for you to interact and check each tab until you quit by pressing `Y`.
- Chrome is default for [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) on macOS and Linux. If you run Windows, Edge will be default, and so you may need to adjust the settings a little if Chrome is preferred.